# How do I count the parentheses in a string?

Tags: java, string, char

This is my method to count the number of parentheses in a string.

```java
public int checkParenthesis(String print, char par){
    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<print.length(); i++){
        if(print.indexOf(i) == par){
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

It doesn't work. It returns 0.
`print` is a random string and `par` is a parenthesis.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) is your friend.  The argument passed to `indexOf` is treated as a character, not as an index.

Comment: as an aside, wouldn't it make more sense to remove the non-parens and then count the remaining chars? you could also do two replacements - one for `(` and another for `)` and compare the counts if you need to balance them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`.charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) to get the current character and compare it with `par`:

```
if(print.charAt(i) == par)
```

Another way to do this:

```
for(char c : print.toCharArray()) {
  if(c == par) {
    num++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You meant `charAt` instead of `indexOf`.

The difference is that `charAt` takes a position in the string (0, 1, ...) and returns the character at that position. `indexOf` takes a character, and searches the string for the first position where that character is found. You're passing an `int` to `indexOf`, not a `char`, but the compiler accepts this "thanks" to implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

In java `indexOf` is used for checking ch at index. Instead of `indexOf` u can use `string.charAt(index)` to get desired result.

```
public int checkParenthesis(String print, char par){
    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<print.length(); i++){
        if(print.charAt(i) == par){
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Instead of saying `used for checking ch at index`, it would be more understandable to say `used for finding the index of a character`

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your current algorithm is examining characters at each index with a loop. That would be appropriate with `String.charAt(int)` but not `String.indexOf(int)`. However, you could certainly implement it with [`String.indexOf(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-). Also, I prefer to check for `null` and an empty input preemptively. Finally, your method counts matching characters (not "checking parenthesis") and doesn't depend on class state so I would make it `static`. Something like,

```
public static int countChar(String print, char par) {
    if (print == null || print.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    int num = 0;
    int pos = -1;
    while ((pos = print.indexOf(par, pos + 1)) != -1) {
        num++;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since *Java 9* you can use [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePoints--) method:

```java
static long characterCount(String str, char ch) {
    // filter the desired characters and return their quantity
    return str.codePoints().filter(cp -> cp == ch).count();
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(characterCount("srting))", ')')); // 2
    System.out.println(characterCount("{srting}", '{')); // 1
    System.out.println(characterCount("(srting)", 's')); // 1
    System.out.println(characterCount("[srting]", 'ё')); // 0
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Recursive method that returns true if the integer exists only once in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66507160/15309136)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just one another way, but with creating extra String objects:

```
 int cnt=print.length()-print.replaceAll(String.valueOf(c),"").length();
```