# Recursive method that returns true if the integer exists only once in an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

For example:

```java
int[] arr = {1,2,2,3,4,5};
```

`3` exists only once the method should return `true`, `2` exists twice the method should return `false`, `0` doesn't exist the method should return `false`. I keep getting a runtime error, how do I fix it or is there any way to the method (recursions only).
Here is my code:

```java
public static boolean list(int[] a, int num) {
    return helper(a, 0, num);
}

public static boolean helper(int[] a, int i, int num) {
    int count = 0;
    if (a[i] == num)
        count++;
    if (count == 1 && i == a.length)
        return true;
    else if (count != 1 && i == a.length)
        return false;
    else
        return helper(a, i++, num);
}
```

Comment: Hint: arrays are 0-indexed. If `i == a.length`, then what would you expect `a[i]` to do?

Comment: at least `i == a.length` must be check *before* any access at index *i*. Out of that *count* is local so cannot do what you want, replace it by a parameter, or use the return value to count the number of occurrences and check helper returns 1

Comment: You should just reorder the checks, start with the `i == a.length` ones, and only then try to access `a[i]`

Comment: NB It always helps to paste the exact error that you get, not just "I get a runtime error". Show the error output (and exception name); that way you will get help and an answer much quicker.

Comment: *"I keep getting a runtime error"* Then you should show us the error, with full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and got a [java.lang.StackOverflowError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html). That indicates that your recursive method, named `helper` keeps calling itself infinitely. It does that because neither of the conditions in the `if` statements that precede the `return` statements are ever true.

You don't want to recursively call the method when one of the following two conditions are true:

1. You have encountered a second occurrence of the number you are searching for in the array.
2. You have reached the end of the array.

If you keep initializing `count` to zero in every call to method `helper`, it will **never** be greater than one. Hence you should make it a parameter of method `helper`.

You just need to check whether `i` equals `a.length` to determine whether you have reached the end of the array.

```java
/**
 * Determines whether 'num' occurs exactly once in 'a'.
 *
 * @param a     - array to search
 * @param count - number of occurrences of 'num' in 'a'
 * @param i     - index in 'a'
 * @param num   - number to search for
 *
 * @return 'true' if 'num' occurs exactly once in 'a', otherwise 'false'.
 */
public static boolean helper2(int[] a, int count, int i, int num) {
    if (count > 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (i == a.length) {
        return count == 1;
    }
    if (a[i] == num) {
        count++;
    }
    return helper2(a, count, i + 1, num);
}
```

And the initial call to the method is (for example, if you are checking whether the number `3` appears only once in the array.

```java
int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // array of integers to search
int count = 0; // number of occurrences
int index = 0; // index in 'a'
int num = 3; // number to search for
boolean single = helper2(a, count, index, num);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to do with an *iterative method*:

```java
public static boolean iterativeMethod(int[] arr, int number) {
    // filter the desired numbers in the array
    // and check if their quantity is equal to '1'
    return Arrays.stream(arr).filter(i -> i == number).count() == 1;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    System.out.println(iterativeMethod(arr, 3)); // true
    System.out.println(iterativeMethod(arr, 2)); // false
    System.out.println(iterativeMethod(arr, 0)); // false
}
```